# Specify a custom table name and set condition on model | Laravel

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent

I have a table named 'users'. In this table, I have a field "user_type" (let say value 13 as property manager). Now I have created a new Eloquent Model(let say "PropertyManager") and I set the following member of the class.

```
/**
 * The table associated with the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'users';
```

Now my question is that I want to set conditionally based table name.
If I run the query like this PropertyManager::all() then it should return all the user whose type is "13". I don't want to set where condition otherwise if the where condition is only the solution then I think I don't need to create a separate Eloquent Model. I can do like User::where(---).

Comment: try [Query scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#query-scopes)

Comment: That is what I want. Thank you, boss. @ab_ab

Answer (score 1):

**Quick and dirty**

Let's take advantage of inheritance!

In your PropertyManager model:

```
public function all()
{
    return User::where('user_type', '13')->get();
}

// Call with PropertyManager::all();
```

This causes you to overload Eloquent's Model default and returns all users that are actually property managers.

**Probably better**

What's more readable and probably accepted is adding methods to your User model like this:

```
class User
{
    // logic

    public static function getAllPropertyManagers()
    {
        return self::where('user_type', '13')->get();
    }
}

// Call with User::getAllPropertyManagers();
```

Since in the end, PropertyManagers are still users, why not put some methods in the User model and load them that way?